Amazon links are broken
I was trying to link to wisdom publication books on amazon, as they are copyright, and just noticed that amazon links are broken.
It seems like it happened years ago and was fixed on stackexchange here.
This is what is showing on buddhism stackexchange: https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003XRDC2K
instead of https://www.amazon.com/Middle-Length-Discourses-Buddha-Translation-ebook/dp/B003XRDC2K

Are they broken?

When I go to https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003XRDC2K then I'm redirected to the correct link.
I'm not sure how they were "fixed", the post you linked to said that the rads.stackoverflow.com domain was down.
Othercomments there and elsewhere say the problem may be caused by using an ad blocker (which I don't).

I don't think they are any different on other sites that here -- for example the post which you linked to i.e. ...

Amazon links are broken network-wide

... references this post on StackOverflow ...

The Definitive C Book Guide and List

... and the links in that post are still in rads format:


I must be behind a something that is blocking the links, thanks for the clarification. I will follow up, glad they are not broken

I also hope that hyperlinks in posts would also include the title of the book, in the text of link -- so that you can read the title whether or not the link it broken. One would be welcome to tell me if any don't, I would fix that.

Greetings @ChrisW, good idea, I will revise the posts in the future to do as you have suggested
